# Why is there an 'ear' component in the character for smell? 闻 聞

Tags: glyph-origin, character-components

Why is there an 'ear' radical in the character for smell? 闻 聞

I find this pretty confusing. Perhaps there is a fun story behind it?

Comment: For the record, in Classical Chinese, 臭 (= 自 originally meaning 'nose' and 犬 for 'dog') was the character for the verb "to smell" as well as the noun "a smell" (and the adjective "odorous").

Comment: @Michaelyus you should mention that in the *to smell* sense, 臭 is pronounced **xiù**.

Answer (score 3):

「聞」(Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*mu[n]/**) is comprised of semantic「耳」(*ear*) and phonetic「門」(**/*mˤə[r]/**), indicating the meaning ***to hear***. For example,「新聞」means *news* (literally meaning *new information passed on by hearing/reading/etc.*)

> 「門」does not play a meaning role in「聞」. For that matter, it does not play a meaning role in「問」, either.

*To smell* is a semantic extension. For example, in English, *there's something fishy going on* is used to describe a situation which is not quite right, literally referring to *the smell of fish*, but metaphorically referring to someone picking up information about their surroundings and deducing that something feels off.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This is a hypothesis, not a fact.

The complex form, 聞, has a rather straightforward ideogrammatic interpretation as a pair of doors (門) with an ear (耳) presenting itself within the space beneath them, suggesting a human placing or centering their ear at or within the frame of the door pair's (door bottom)-(floor top) gap to hear sound issuing from the space behind said door. (This, in addition to that 門 is phonetically similar to 聞.) Hence, it has the meaning of **hearing**, i.e. hearing sound (音), perhaps whatever is going on on the other side of the door (i.e. snooping).

This element is used in more complex pieces with the meaning *hearing* - e.g. see the compounds section on Wiktionary:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%81%9E

e.g. 但聞. These suggest that, in a sense, the notion of "hear" became more generalized to the application of other sense organs - such as the nose - to an object of interests as well, essentially, to, more generally, "hear a smell" with the nose. It's generalized hearing, if you will, and carries the cognition of sensation or detection as a concept being a generalization of the notion of gathering information through the employment of the ear.

Answer (score 0):

Baidu has [this](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E2%80%9C%E9%97%BB%E2%80%9D%E7%9A%84%E8%AF%8D%E4%B9%89%E8%BD%AC%E5%8F%98/14697452):

“闻”字在先秦时期**已经被用来表示嗅到**，《韩非子 · 十过》有**“闻酒臭而还”**。我相信当时口语中**表示嗅到的词与“闻”同音**，但**没有专字**，所以借用“闻”字来表示。这种现象在汉字中很普遍，如“朋”、“来”、“其”、“而”等等。如此观之，“闻”表示“嗅到”有可能是**假借义**。由广变窄，变专的过程。文学接受进入高潮阶段的一种更高境界，是指读者在阅读文学作品，与之形成共鸣，并达到净化后进入的更高阶段，包括潜思默想、洞悉宇宙奥妙、体悟人生真谛和提升精神境界等状况与过程。 我个人简单认为： 领悟就是心灵受到某种触动，而使智慧知识上升等级的过程。

Are the senses really all 1 sense? Is everyhting just in our minds? I recently read that the structures known as tastebuds are found in many other places in our bodies, apart from our mouths.

见 is see, but 听见 is hear.

There is a condition known as synesthesia. If you suffer from this, you may smell music, hear tastes.